# Form 'submit' button always ending with error

Tags: php, html, forms

I've created a simple contact form using [this sample by CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/nice-and-simple-contact-form/). It worked great until I customised the `contactthanks.php` page (confirmation of successful form submission). Now every time the user hits 'Submit', they are redirected to the error page.

Live page: [alookat.org/contact.html](http://alookat.org/contact.html) (feel free to test form).

The following is the `contactengine.php` which broke things after I edited it. I removed the Telephone input and replaced it with Website. I also re-orded the inputs.

```
<?php

$EmailFrom = "info@example.com";
$EmailTo = "my.personal.email.was.here.for.testing@gmail.com";
$Subject = "Thanks for contacting us";
$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name']));  
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 
$Website = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Website']));
$Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message'])); 

// validation
$validationOK=true;
if (!$validationOK) {
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
  exit;
}

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $Name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Website: ";
$Body .= $Website;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $Message;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=php\contactthanks.php\">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
}
?>
```

Thanks for your help. Thanks for reading.

Comment: "The following is the contactengine.php which broke things after I edited it." Broke things, how? What's your exact problem?

Comment: You should be using `echo` instead of `print` - it is (marginally) faster and does not return a value, unlike `print`.

Answer (score 2):

Using that

```
<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
```

Is a really nasty way of moving the user to a new page.

You are in PHP so use the `header()` function instead.

```
header('Location: php/contactthanks.php');
exit;
```

This way you just send a header which tells the browser to go to another page, rather than the whole page of html.

You can use this in all 3 place where you are using `<meta http-equiv...>` tags

Comment: Does this really solve the problem? What about the `php\contactthanks`? Shouldn’t it be `php\/contactthanks` or just `php/contactthanks`?

Comment: Well spotted, my mistake. I changed the slash to a unix slash as it should be. I have no way of knowing your directory structure so I have to assume `php/contactthanks.php` is a valid relative path to `contactthanks.php`.

Comment: You also should have an `exit` or `die` statement after the `header` statement.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Interesting, thanks. Do I still include the `print` before the `header()` function? Example: `print header('Location: php/contactthanks.php');`

Comment: No the print is not required. `header()` send a header to the browser right there and then, and thats all it sends. That causes the browser to call for the page entered as the parameter to `header()`. Thats why @Chad reminded me you should follow every `header()` with an exit, to stop further execution of this script dead in its tracks.

Comment: Oh and just to complete the information - You should make `header()` calls only before you send anything else to the browser, so these kind of tests should be done first in your script, before you send any other output to the browser

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks for all your info & suggestions. The main problem still exists though—the submission always ends in error (even with your changes/optimisations)